# How to extract the public address from the private seed in python?

Tags: python-sdk

Given the private seed, how do I get the public address in Python using Stellar's SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out to be pretty simple:

```
from stellar_base.keypair import Keypair 
print('address: %s' % Keypair.from_seed(my_seed).address().decode())
```